# List of a list of a lists as an input to LSTM keras

Tags: python, list, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have a list of 5 lists which contains a list of 4000 lists each with different sizes. How can I convert it into a NumPy array to give it as my input to Keras LSTM as

```
model.add(layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(None, 5), return_sequences=True))
```

```
X: list of 5 (number of features)
X[0]: list of 4000 (number of training data)
X[0][0]: list of 6 (no. of points where the size vary every time)
```

Before with the zero-padding, I was making the last length 10 and was getting a numpy array of size (4000,10,5) and giving input as **input_shape=(10,5)**. Now i am not sure what to do as the length varies.

Comment: What kind of array do you need?  `shape`, `dtype`?

Comment: Do you have to make arrays ? When you have structures with varying lengths, you could consider using dictionaries

Comment: That is what I am confused about. Lets say for the above case (5,4000,6) which will be the input to LSTM. where 5 are my number of features so i would give it as `(None,5)´

Comment: @NHL I have to give it as an input to LSTM, it should be dataframe or numpy array

Comment: Why did you abandon the idea of using padding? Input length should almost always be consistent

Comment: Cause, 20% of the data becomes zero and i wasn't doing masking. Hence, the model was pretty much unstable. I am trying the masking now. let's ee

Comment: Even with the masking the network is not learning anything. @NicolasGervais

Comment: you can try RaggedTensor to avoid padding/masking. But some tensorflow operations are not possible with RaggedTensor